# In manifest :tools:replace="android:resource" not a solution

Tags: android, manifest

Below is the information I get from the android manifest merged when I attempt to build.

```
Error: Attribute property#android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG@resource value=(@xml/gma_ad_services_config) from AndroidManifest.xml:92:13-59 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-58 value=(@xml/ga_ad_services_config). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to \<property\> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override. AttenptToAddFolders.app main manifest (this file), line 91
```

Below is the XML code in my manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"\>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/\>                               <application
android:fullBackupContent="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/phrasesagain"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/phrasesagain"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AttemptToAddFolders"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:screenOrientation = "portrait"
tools:ignore="DataExtractionRules"\>
```

I don't know what to do if I add `tools:replace="android:resource"` (as suggested) to either the `\<manifest xmlns\>` or the  `\<application\>`, nothing changes.

I added `tools:replace="android:resource"` as suggested first to the `\<manifest xmlns\>`, this did not yield a successful  build. Second, I added the suggestion to `\<application\>` which did not yield a successful  build either.